# How do I get the div ID in AngularJS

Tags: arrays, html, angularjs, object, dom

I have a div created by an array of objects using ng-repeat. Within that div is a tiny secondary div meant to act as a delete. When I click the second div I want the object to be removed from the array.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" id = "doc:{{$index}}">
    <div ng-model="remove" ng-click="removefunc()" id="{{$index}}">
        x
    </div>
    Other stuff goes here...
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.removefunc = function() {
    $scope.items.splice(ID of the div,1);
}
```

Is this the right way to do this? and if so, how do I get the ID of the div?

Comment: nevermind.... just pass it $index works <facepalm>
ng-click="removefunc($index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple fixes for you (the `id` tag is not necessary for what you are doing):

Pass the index into the function so it knows which one.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-model="remove" ng-click="removefunc($index)">
        x
    </div>
    Other stuff goes here...
</div>
```

And:

Use that index in the splice.

```
$scope.removefunc = function(index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
}
```

*Please note that if you have filters on your repeater than this will not work*

Comment: Thank you. I too realized that the id was not needed and have since removed them.